# LazyColumn animateScrollBy does nothing?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Update: original question followed by updated sample code that triggers it as requested.

I have a list of times broken down by half hour in a lazy list

E.g  12:00, 12:30

The list is attached to a horizontal pager from the accompanist-pager library

When a user is swiping between pages, I need to update the selected time, and I want the selected time to always be in the center of the screen, if it's not near the top/bottom where that can't be the case.

The only way I've figured out how to accurately do this with the methods provided to us is as below.

Note: i have previously captured the button / list height.

```
  val listState = rememberLazyListState()

  LaunchedEffect(pagerState) {
            snapshotFlow { pagerState.currentPage }.collect { page ->
                if (page != selectedPage) {
                    listState.scrollToItem(0) //Need to be at the top for calc below to work
                    listState.scrollBy(buttonHeight.toFloat() * page - (listVisibleHeight / 2) + buttonHeight)
                }
            }
        }
```

Now this works perfectly. When I start at 00:00 and move down the list no scrolling occurs until I reach the middle, and once I reach the middle, the selected time, stays in the middle as the times scroll accordingly, and remains in the middle until I approach the end of the list where it starts moving downwards.

Now there's also a method `listState.animateScrollBy(float, animation)` which would be ideal so there's an animation if you have clicked on something not in the middle, and it has to animate it back to the middle, but when I use this one absolutely nothing happens?

```
   listState.animateScrollBy(buttonHeight.toFloat() * page - (listVisibleHeight / 2) + buttonHeight)
```

It just seems flat out broken to me?  As if I never called the function. 0 scrolling, even when I try adding a non default animation. Am I doing something wrong here?

It's doing this on compose 1.2.0-alpha04 and 1.2.0-alpha06

I can continue to use scrollBy but without the animation, it will be a little jumpy if the user clicks a time vs swipes to a time.

---

Example now that I know why it's happening as requested

Special Imports for the pager

```
  implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.24.5-alpha"
  implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:0.24.5-alpha"
```

Note: The pager itself has been wonky since I updated it to fix a crash in an earlier version... it doesn't quite swipe right, it gets stuck at times.  I have not looked into it yet at all though.

```
import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.animateScrollBy
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.rememberLazyListState
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.onGloballyPositioned
import com.google.accompanist.pager.ExperimentalPagerApi
import com.google.accompanist.pager.HorizontalPager
import com.google.accompanist.pager.PagerState

@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Composable
fun TestScreen() {
    val numberOfRows = 48

    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    var selectedRow by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var buttonHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var listVisibleHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val pagerState = PagerState(currentPage = selectedRow)

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .onGloballyPositioned {
                listVisibleHeight = it.size.height
            }
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            state = listState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
            items(numberOfRows) { index ->
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .wrapContentWidth()
                        .onGloballyPositioned {
                            buttonHeight = it.size.height
                        },
                    onClick = {}
                ) {
                    if (index == selectedRow) {
                        Text(text = index.toString(), color = Color.White)
                    } else {
                        Text(text = index.toString(), color = Color.Red)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        LaunchedEffect(pagerState) {
            snapshotFlow { pagerState.currentPage }.collect { page ->
                if (page != selectedRow) {
                    //This doesn't work if selectedRow = page happens before the other code due to recomposition
                    //If it's after, it executes but it doesn't look right as it moves then highlights

                    selectedRow = page

                    listState.scrollToItem(0)
                    try {
                        listState.animateScrollBy(distanceToMiddleOfScreen(buttonHeight, listVisibleHeight, page))
                    } catch (exception: Exception) {
                        Log.e("scrollBug", "animateScrollBy Exception", exception)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        HorizontalPager(
            count = 48,
            state = pagerState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .background(Color.White),
        ) { page ->
            Text(text = page.toString())
        }
    }
}

private fun distanceToMiddleOfScreen(itemHeight: Int, totalListHeight: Int, offset: Int): Float {
    return itemHeight.toFloat() * offset - (totalListHeight / 2) + itemHeight
}
```

Comment: Not related to the issue itself: I think scrolling item to the center/to the bottom of the view is needed too, that's why I've created such [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/226929291), so you don't have to calculate list size and animation can work properly. Please star it to bring more attention.

Comment: As to the issue: generally `animateScrollBy` for sure work fine, why it doesn't work in your case is your job to debug. I'd start with wrapping with try/catch to see if there's any error thrown, adding logs before/after the call, changing `animationSpec` parameter, launching it separately on `rememberCoroutineScope` inside `collect`.

Comment: That's not a super helpful start to your second message.  Of course I had tried numerous things.  Different locations, different values, different coroutines, all to no avail. I don't want to waste my time writing all that for something that should just be working?  But I will say the one thing I didn't try was try/catch because it wasn't logging any problem or crashing.  But it turns out animating is throwing a silent error 'StandaloneCoroutine was cancelled; job=StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@3274e75'.  So thank you.  I can look into it now that there's something to look into.

Comment: The issue was a recomposition was cancelling it.  I'll figure out how to re work it, or possibly bail on the animation entirely as at least with the current settings, it looks pretty bad for my purpose.

Comment: so your `LaunchedEffect` is being relaunched? It's strange, since `pagerState` should be a static value, so recomposition shouldn't cause relaunch. Try to pass `Unit` instead of `pagerState`, but I don't think it should help. If you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I'll be able to say what's happening.

Comment: I added a basic example to the bottom of my question.  Unit didn't work, and broke the paging.  If I use rememberCoroutineScope and use a button onClick instead of the LaunchedEffect, it works, but I can't do that in this specific scenario.  Also the pager is acting weird, as I noted in the question with the new code, I have yet to look into that since updating the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pager behaves strangely because you're creating its state on reach recomposition:

```
val pagerState = PagerState(currentPage = selectedRow)
```

This initializer made for you to use in your own state, which you're responsible to remember between recompositions.

In case when you use it in the view, to save its state between recompositions you need to use remember version:

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
```

After this your `LaunchedEffect` won't be restarted and won't stop your `animateScrollBy`.

---

I can't think of a general solution of scrolling problem until this [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/226929291) is closed. But in case when all your items have equal size, you can calculate current scroll position, final scroll position, and so you can calculate the difference to scroll:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    snapshotFlow { pagerState.currentPage }.collect { page ->
        if (page != selectedRow) {
            selectedRow = page

            val currentOffset = listState.firstVisibleItemIndex * buttonHeight + listState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
            val finalOffset = distanceToMiddleOfScreen(buttonHeight, listVisibleHeight, page)
            listState.animateScrollBy(finalOffset - currentOffset)
        }
    }
}
```

Also your `distanceToMiddleOfScreen` is not accurate, it can be fixed like this:

```
return itemHeight * (offset + 0.5f) - totalListHeight / 2
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Ya, that does it. Thank you.  It also explains the pager bit.  I went from something like 0.15 -> 0.24.5 to fix a known crash this morning, but they redid how pagerState worked and I guess I screwed that one up!  I only started debugging that to the point of horizontal scrolling not acting weird on 0.24.2 and broken on 0.24.3 so you probably saved me a pile of further troubleshooting there.  You killed 2 birds with 1 stone on that mistake.

Comment: Also funny that about the scroll, in my actual app its right and yours is off, but I think its something to do with toolbars because yours is right on the test app and mine is wrong.  Something to figure out tomorrow morning!

Comment: Also your calculation with the finalOffset - currentOffset is much better.  With the animateScrollBy now working, mine had a stutter as it went to top and animated down.